# RSpec error "Uninitialized constant FactoryGirl (Name Error)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I try running my RSpec test:

```
rspec comments.rb
```

but keep getting the same error (see title). Before anyone asks I have already added `require factory_girl` to spec_helper.rb.

The contents of `spec/factories/comments.rb` file are:

```
  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :comment do
      comment "MyString"
      task_id 1
  end
end
```

Here is testing group of the gemfile where I included factory_girl_rails:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

...

group :development, :test do
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

...
```

Answer (score 91):

You just have to add the following in your spec_helper.rb file

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
```

Comment: FactoryGirl has changed its name to FactoryBot, so you will now need to use `require 'factory_bot_rails'`.

Answer (score -13):

Do this:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:artist).should be_valid
```

Comment: This answer uses the unknown constant `FactoryGirl`.  How is this supposed to help?

Comment: I'm voting to delete this answer as it's not addressing the question that was asked.