# RSpec, Rails 4.1 and FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

Okay,

this is driving me nuts really.
I've scoured through a lot of posts on Stackoverflow trying to resolve this, but none of the solutions seem to be working.

This is the error message I'm getting when running the command: ***bundle exec rspec***

```
c700595:vtm deh0002a$ bundle exec rspec
/Users/deh0002a/IdeaProjects/vtm/spec/spec_helper.rb:83:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant FactoryGirl (NameError)
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core.rb:81:in `configure'
from /Users/deh0002a/IdeaProjects/vtm/spec/spec_helper.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1072:in `require'
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1072:in `block in requires='
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1072:in `each'
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1072:in `requires='
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:103:in `block in process_options_into'
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:102:in `each'
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:102:in `process_options_into'
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:22:in `configure'
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:95:in `setup'
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.1.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

So first I looked up the error I'm getting.
From the information I could find, this seems to be missing configuration, so I followed all steps again I could find on the gem pages and the posts on stackoverflow.

***Gemfile***

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
# Use mysql2 as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Development and Test environment
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

***spec_helper.rb***

```
# This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause this
# file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, consider making
# a separate helper file that requires the additional dependencies and performs
# the additional setup, and require it from the spec files that actually need it.
#
# The `.rspec` file also contains a few flags that are not defaults but that
# users commonly want.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
    # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
    # defined using `chain`, e.g.:
    # be_bigger_than(2).and_smaller_than(4).description
    #   # => "be bigger than 2 and smaller than 4"
    # ...rather than:
    #   # => "be bigger than 2"
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  # These two settings work together to allow you to limit a spec run
  # to individual examples or groups you care about by tagging them with
  # `:focus` metadata. When nothing is tagged with `:focus`, all examples
  # get run.
  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  # Limits the available syntax to the non-monkey patched syntax that is recommended.
  # For more details, see:
  #   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax
  #   - http://teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3#new__config_option_to_disable_rspeccore_monkey_patching
  config.disable_monkey_patching!

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed

  # Load FactoryGirl Methods
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

I created a **/spec/factories.rb*** and defined my Factory there according to the documentation specified on the FactoryGirl page.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following in `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
```

See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715519/having-trouble-with-rspec-testing-uninitialized-constant-factorygirl-name-erro).

Comment: Throws up the following error:

    /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionview-4.1.6/lib/action_view/template.rb:8:in `<class:Template>': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Autoload (NameError)

Comment: Try to add the following `require 'rubygems'`, 
`require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)`, and 
`Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}`

Comment: See [link-1](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14664), [link-2](https://github.com/nulldb/nulldb/issues/38)

Comment: will try it out tommorow when I'm back at work.
Is this changed behavior in the newer version, because all of this has been running fine on older versions.

Comment: actually tried just adding _require 'factory_girl'__ to my spec_helper and now RSpec works, but the factories are not being recognized by FactoryGirl for some reason.

I have the feeling something changed big time in this latest rails regarding to autoloading and paths...